# ngDoc can't cope with the Angular styleguide

Tags: angularjs, naming-conventions, ngdoc

I have just taken a look at [ngDoc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation), and even though documentation is sparse, I understand it needs a very specific namespacing syntax in the `@name` tag, for instance

```
    moduleName.directive:directiveName
```

in the case of a directive (gleaned this from [here](https://github.com/idanush/ngdocs/wiki/API-Docs-Syntax#directives)).

However, the [officially endorsed Angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y020) says we should namespace our modules with dots (e.g. `app.users`).

Now, am I just not getting it, or are those two things mutually exclusive?!?

Is there a way to escape the `moduleName` for ngDoc? I really don't feel particularly like renaming all my modules (plus, I happen to think the styleguide makes sense)...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. For anyone coming across this and experiencing the same behavior:

If you happen to be using the grunt-ngdocs plugin, try uninstalling and reinstalling it:

```
npm remove grunt-ngdocs
npm install grunt-ngdocs
```